# Show/hide jquery plugin - my previous div stays open

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I´m using this jquery Show/hide plugin http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/

I intend to close previous div **on click any link** on my page, but as I click on a new link my previous div stays open.

My html

```
<div id="slidingDiv_2" class"toggleDiv"><!-- Conteúdo do menu 1 -->
      <div class="opmenu">
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#!">CENTROS DE ACTIVIDADES NOS TEMPOS LIVRES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">SERVI&Ccedil;O DE ATENDIMENTO E ACOMPANHAMENTO SOCIAL</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">CENTRO COMUNIT&Aacute;RIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">APARTAMENTO PARA A AUTONOMIA DE VIDA</a></li>
        </ul>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
    </div>
```

my link:

```
<li class="items_menu"><a href="#" class="show_hide" rel="#slidingDiv">A INSTITUIÇÃO</a></li>
```

my js:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

        //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: 'easeInQuart',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Mostrar',
            hideText: 'Ocultar'

        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () { 

             $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);    
             // this var stores which button you've clicked
             var toggleClick = $(this);
             // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
             var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
             // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
             $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
             // this only fires once the animation is completed
             if(options.changeText==1){
             $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
             }
              });

          return false;

        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: why do you need such a simple plugin while its all by `jQuery('#slidingDiv').slideToggle('slow')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need any plug-in, and if you also don't want to use jquery ui accordion.

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/HmwN8/2/

- Add `rel` tag in `a` tag with your DIV's id that you want to open.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.toggle').on('click', function(){
        $('.content').slideUp('2000', "easeOutBounce");        
        if($('div#'+$(this).attr('rel')).css('display')=='block')
            $('div#'+$(this).attr('rel')).slideUp('2000', "easeOutBounce");
        else
            $('div#'+$(this).attr('rel')).slideDown('2000', "easeOutBounce");
    });
});
```

- You can choose the effect you want here http://jqueryui.com/effect/#easing

## HTML

```
<a class="toggle" rel="div_1">View 1</a>
<a class="toggle" rel="div_2">View 2</a>
<a class="toggle" rel="div_3">View 3</a>
<div class="content" id="div_1">( 1 ) Lorem Ipsum ...</div>
<div class="content" id="div_2">( 2 ) Lorem Ipsum ...</div>
<div class="content" id="div_3">( 3 ) Lorem Ipsum ...</div>
```

Comment: I didn't quite manage to put this working the way I want.
This example shows the expected result:
http://bree.com

Comment: Thanks, your example really help me. 
I change de code so my links don't open in a new tab, using Rel attribute instead off target.

And I add close button to my content DIVs.

Now I have a new difficulty:

I need to close my div when I click on the same option link.

Comment: Thanks it really help,works really nice on my project. I'v learn a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To close the div when click on any link

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
    $('Selectorfordiv').slideUp(); // or slideToggle or css({'display':'none'})
});
```

Possible to when the div becomes visible to add a Class, so you can target this Class to close when clicked on any link.

PS. for show/hide don't use a plugin it will cost more resources then writing the lines yourself.